# how wo change pytest Generated parameters

Tags: python, pytest

is there any possible change the test_zerodivision param when execute test_equals function

when test_equals is running test_zerodivision function param is a=1 b=0, but i want to change a or b value in this function

can i change TestClass.params  then reload pytest_generate_tests or any other ways

i konw how to avoid this problem,but i just want know how change the value.
pytest use a lot of black magic, I'm just curious

```
import pytest


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    # called once per each test function
    funcarglist = metafunc.cls.params[metafunc.function.__name__]
    argnames = sorted(funcarglist[0])
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, [[funcargs[name] for name in argnames]
            for funcargs in funcarglist])

class TestClass(object):
    # a map specifying multiple argument sets for a test method
    params = {
        'test_equals': [dict(a=1, b=2), dict(a=3, b=3), ],
        'test_zerodivision': [dict(a=1, b=0), ],
    }

    def test_equals(self, a, b):

        assert a == b

    def test_zerodivision(self, a, b):
        with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
            a / b
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for [pytest.mark.parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html). Here is an example of how to implement this functionalty under your code:

```
import pytest


class TestClass:    
    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ('a', 'b'),
        (
            (1, 1),
            (3, 3),
            ('a', 'a')
        )

    )
    def test_equal(self, a, b):
        assert a == b

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        ('a', 'b'),
        (
            (1, 0),
            (0, 0),
            (0.1, 0)
        )
    )
    def test_zerodivision(self, a, b):
        with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError):
            a / b
```